# Internet connectivity in iphone when application is minimize

Tags: iphone

i want to check  for internet availability in whenever my application make call to webservice during my application was minimized.
I had done some google work and found this :-
[How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=635200

But this doesnt not gives me how do i check when application is minimized i.e paused!!
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application is running in background mode you cannot check for internet connectivity. You can run audio, VOIP or location services in background mode. 
Any open or listening sockets will be closed when the application enters background mode.

Comment: @ werner.Thanks for the reply .I had achieved this by writing method in delegate class.But it was For ios4 and for further version